# "substr" statement in apache pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, substr

I have below user data structure in apache hadoop

```
21796346,83637,2990666,1,2,false,0,0
21827841,15748,8754621,1,7,true,0,1
```

First 4 digits of the 1st field represent the user type.
2nd field represents the department type.

I would like to query the number of user types in each department. 
SQL statement is below

```
select dept_id, substr(User_Id,1,4) as user_type, count(*) as number_of_users from users group by dept_id,substr(User_Id,1,4)
```

I could not figure out how to define substr function in pig.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could youse SUBSTRING in PIG

```
A = LOAD 'DATA' USING PigStorage(';') AS (User_Id, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7); 
B = GROUP A By SUBSTRING(User_Id,1,4);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group as user_typeX, COUNT(A) as number_of_users_with_the_same_user_typeX;
```

To get the number of all users you could GROUP BY ALL.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the complete list of Pig's built-in functions [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/func.html). The function you are looking for is called `SUBSTRING`. Note that function names in Pig are case-sensitive.